# Simulating compilation error

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Yesterday I tried to inject compilation error in my working tree. Usually I use #error to generate compilation error. But I tried #1 but it doesn't work. What could be the reason for this?

```
t1.c 
     #include <stdio.h>
     int main (){
            #error
     }

**compilation error**
t1.c:3:3: error: 
        #error
t2.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main (){
        #1
    }

But there is no compilation error in t2.c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variations on the theme of `# 1` etc are generated by the C preprocessor as a shorthand for `#line 1`.

It is non-standard, but common.

You can probably see it in the output from `gcc -E` or similar options that only run the preprocessor.